# Laravel task not running - No scheduled commands are ready to run

Tags: php, laravel

I have a task in Kernel.php set up like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
       $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\UserAccountsController@salesAddToDB')
                ->everyMinute();
   }
```

On forge I have it set like:

`148957 Custom  * * * * *   forge   php /home/forge/default/artisan schedule:run`

On my live server I tried `php artisan schedule:run`

both I get the error `No scheduled commands are ready to run.`

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: same here. I having the problem.

Comment: have you solved it? Any clue for this problem?

Comment: @crossRT my issue was my schedule was for the 'default' site and not my actual site. So say your site is `acoolsite.com` you need to have your schedule task point there `/home/forge/acoolsite.com/artisan schedule:run`